# HighStocks - x-axis Gridlines on each separate y-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm trying to draw x-axis gridlines on each y-axis of the chart. Right now the x-axis gridline extends through all of the y-axis with no separation or stops between each y-axis.

Here is how I'm getting now[image]

the code for the x-axis

```
xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 5,
            minTickInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000,
            lineColor: '#000',
            tickColor: '#000',
            startOnTick: true,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    color: '#000',
                    font: '11px Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'
                }
            },
            title: {
                style: {
                    color: '#333',
                    fontWeight: 'bold',
                    fontSize: '12px',
                    fontFamily: 'Trebuchet MS, Verdana, sans-serif'

                }
            }
        },
```

How can I prevent the line from extending to all the chart i.e. on all y-axis. This is what I want it to be like [image]

Please let me know how can I achieve the desired result. I will appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Maxx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's interesting, because this is how it works in Highstock 1.3.10, see: http://jsfiddle.net/4qGKE/

```
        xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1  
        },
```

However Highcharts doesn't support this for now ( see: http://jsfiddle.net/4qGKE/1/ ) .

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Yes i'm using HighStocks. But even with xAxis: {
            gridLineWidth: 1  
        },                                                                          I don't get the desired results. Only the width of the x-axis have decreased by some pixels.

Comment: But I initialize it using chart1 = new Highcharts.StockChart(options, function(chart) { // apply the date pickers setTimeout(function() { $('range-selector', $('#' + options.chart.renderTo)).datepicker() }, 10); }); I hope thats not causing the problem. Please do let me know

Comment: No, it shouldn't cause the problem. Make sure you are using Highstock 1.3.10 (in JS console type `Highcharts.version`)

Comment: Oh this is what i get console.log(Highcharts.version);
1.3.7

Comment: Yes ! It worked flawlessly upon updating the version to 1.3.10. Really thanks for this wonderful fix.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can, in actuality.

Several possible ways around it:

- using the renderer to draw a box over each area to hide them
- set up each gap as another y axis, and use a white plotBand to hide them

None of them are clean, but...

Comment: Thanks for your concern. But can you provide some guide on how to create separate x-axis for each y-axis. I think its the most accessible method. But as i'm fairly a novice with HighStocks so the actual implementation details are unknown to me. Can you provide some guide

Comment: Actually, in trying to set up an example, I see that the x axis option really isn't an option.  I have edited the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Using an existing example (from Pawel, below), I used the plot bands approach here:  http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/4qGKE/3/